# Keep form data after errors on basic Shopify contact form when form fields are in loop

Tags: forms, shopify, form-data

I got the solution for keeping the field data when having error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545528/keep-form-data-after-errors-on-basic-shopify-contact-form).

But my form fields are in loop so when I use 
{{form.varName_ofField}} it does not work.
Please help...

Answer (score 1):

You can only access the `form` variable within a `form` object. For example:

```
{% form 'contact' %}
  available here: {{form.email}}
{% endform %}

but not here: {{form.email}}
```

Comment: I am writing {{form.inputTagId}} within the form opening and closing tag. Its like this -  {% form 'contact' %}
 for(var = setting.[var]) { <input id="{{var}}" type ...> }
{% endform %} (this way)